# EJB Schedule Annotation Stopped working

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, ejb, schedule

I have a method that sends an email at a specific time using the EJB @Schedule annotation. It was working completely fine before and was working for the last few weeks, and was sending the emails at the designated time. However today, it has stopped working and I haven't changed any of the code in that method. I did however, do some JUnit test cases and I tried to create a test case for the send email method, in which I invoked the send email method manually in the code for the test case. I think that may have messed up the EJB timer, since my method stopped working soon after I started running the JUnit test cases. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you deploy after these tests, or do these tests interact with the server? What server brand and version are you using?

Comment: Doesn't seems related since JUnit tests would run only at dev time and the EJB probably runs at a container. Were there any changes to the server?

Comment: I use IBM Websphere Application Server. I am not aware of any changes in the server. I was deploying my application to the server earlier in the day, and it was working fine and sending the emails. Later that day I tried to run my program on the server, after doing JUnit tests, the @Schedule send email method wasn't being called. In my JUnit tests. Since I invoked my send email method in the JUnit class and added all the ejb imports etc..., I feel like it messed something up. I came across this https://www.java.net/node/706287 although the answer did not solve my problem

Comment: Do you have a try/catch inside the \@schedule method? If you catch an exception inside any \@schedule method, it will be called one more time in 5 seconds, and if that fails, the timer dies. Maybe that happened during your testing?

Comment: The reason why that would happen is if an exception was thrown, probably because timeouts when trying to connect to mail server. Check your logs if there was an exception trace